# Short cut for invoking shell script in unix

Tags: unix

I have below two file to start and stop my spring-boot application. Is it possible to have this installed as server etc in unix? so that I can just type `start app` or  `stop app` to start or stop my application from any location?

```
startApplication.sh
stopApplication.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always define alias in your bash, do as below:

```
sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

go at the end of file and add this line

```
alias start-app='bash /<path-to-script>/startApplications.sh'
```

save and exit and resource it with source command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

now if you type in your terminal `start-app` it will execute your script. create one for stop-app too.